# Convert specific time format to common one

Tags: postgresql, datetime, type-conversion, time

- **Environment:**

I have 'duration' datas stored as varchar(4) in a table.
2 first characters are `hours`, 2 last characters are `minutes`. E.g.:

```
0100 means 01:00
0456 means 04:56
```

and so on...

---

- **What I need:**

I  have to make a query that retrieve this field as a common time format : `HH:MM`

---

- **What I have tried:**

No real clue at the moment. I tried to cast my value as `interval`, but it doesn't behave as expected

```
> SELECT time_field, time_field::interval FROM myTable...

> OUTPUT:
0100    |    01:40
0120    |    02:00
0179    |    02:59
```

I would like to avoid use of substring to add `':'` in between 2 characters pairs.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a `timestamp` and then cast that to a `time` value:

```
select time_field, to_timestamp(time_field, 'hh24mi')::time
from the_table
```